# Bluetooth speaker volume and playback control

Tags: 16.04, sound, lubuntu, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a Bluetooth speaker that I use quite frequently with my Lubuntu 16.04 install.

Playback works fine, however I would love to be able to control playback from the speaker's buttons, and also synchronize the volume control buttons on the speaker with the volume control in pavucontrol. I've seen these things work on a Mac, so I know the capacity does at least exist in the hardware!

Does the software exist for handling the control messages? If so what is it, and how do I make a start linking it all together?

Comment: Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and then [edit] your post to include what you've tried, and any other pertinent research that you've accomplished so we don't waste time offering solutions you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer i experienced the same problem and found the solution by going to the "sound" settings on the computer. Then you just have to click on your bluetooth device, leaving the selection of the internal speakers.

Worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of surprised this hasn't been answered properly. The solution is simple.

The media controls has to be controlled by starting the `mpris-proxy` server. After starting the server, your controls on the speaker/headset works like it would with your phone.

Comment: For completeness sake: You might have to search for the `mpris-proxy`; on 18.04 it's `/usr/lib/bluetooth/mpris-proxy` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/bluez/filelist)