# Bluetooth speaker or headphones volume and playback control (MPRIS)

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I would love to use the Volume +/-, Play, Pause and Skip buttons of my Bluetooth speaker when connected to my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.

Found an old question here: [Bluetooth speaker volume and playback control](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904028/bluetooth-speaker-volume-and-playback-control) , but no solution that would be working with 20.04, because the bluez-utils package is not available any more and I can't get mpris-proxy.

Answer (score 1):

`mpris-proxy` is available in `bluez`, path `/usr/lib/bluetooth/mpris-proxy`.

I would also suggest looking at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MPRIS#Bluetooth for automatically starting the service.